# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'persistenceUnit' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm stuck with this and I've tried many similar solutions from here

I have a Spring Boot application deployed in Wildfly 11

This is the deploy error:

```
"{\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myapp\" => \"java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'canalesController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'list'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CeEncuestasList': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'persistenceUnit' available
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'canalesController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'list'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CeEncuestasList': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'persistenceUnit' available
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'canalesController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'list'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CeEncuestasList': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'persistenceUnit' available
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CeEncuestasList': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'persistenceUnit' available
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'persistenceUnit' available\"}}"
```

Console deploy:

```
14:39:55,146 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for persistenceUnit
14:39:55,437 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'myapp.war#persistenceUnit'
14:39:55,457 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: persistenceUnit
    ...]
14:39:55,536 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.10.Final}
14:39:55,538 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
14:39:55,538 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
14:39:55,588 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
14:39:55,659 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
14:39:55,667 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
14:39:55,669 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
14:39:55,669 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
14:39:55,669 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
14:39:55,719 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-7) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final
14:39:55,749 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0013: Deployment myapp.war contains CDI annotations but no bean archive was found (no beans.xml or class with bean defining annotations was present).
14:39:55,799 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'myapp.war#persistenceUnit'
14:39:55,949 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) IJ000407: No lazy enlistment available for gisCexDS
14:39:55,964 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
14:39:55,996 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
14:39:58,101 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
14:39:58,101 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@5c14ba5d
14:39:58,101 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Envers integration enabled? : true
14:39:58,339 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final
14:39:58,671 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
14:39:59,072 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) 
14:39:59,072 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   .   ____          _            __ _ _
14:39:59,072 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
14:39:59,072 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
14:39:59,072 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
14:39:59,072 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
14:39:59,072 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
14:39:59,072 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77)  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)
14:39:59,072 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) 
14:39:59,141 INFO  [com.mytest.test.Application] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) Starting Application on PCSISSVA-ASU10 with PID 12568 (started by figuerel in C:\Users\figuerel\Downloads\wildfly-11.0.0.Final\wildfly-11.0.0.Final\bin)
14:39:59,141 INFO  [com.mytest.test.Application] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
14:39:59,458 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
14:39:59,473 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 6ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
14:39:59,874 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
14:39:59,874 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 717 ms
14:40:00,361 WARN  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'canalesController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'list'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CeEncuestasList': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'persistenceUnit' available
14:40:00,371 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
14:40:00,391 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field list in com.mytest.test.controller.CanalesController required a bean named 'persistenceUnit' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'persistenceUnit' in your configuration.

14:40:00,391 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myapp: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./myapp: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'canalesController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'list'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CeEncuestasList': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'persistenceUnit' available
```

this is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mytest</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.mytest.test.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <!--exclusion para wildfly-->

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <!--exclusion para wildfly-->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--para wildfly-->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->

        <!--para wildfly-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>11.0.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

SpringBoot Application

```
package com.mytest.test;


import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.XADataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.MultipartConfigFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.mytest.test.repository")
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {


    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakSpringBootConfigResolver(){
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}
```

Repository

```
package com.mytest.test.repository;

import com.mytest.test.domain.CeEncuestas;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class CeEncuestasList  extends GenericEncuestasList<CeEncuestas>{
    public CeEncuestasList() {
        super(CeEncuestas.class);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.mytest.test.controller;


import com.mytest.test.domain.CeEncuestas;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class CanalesController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CeEncuestasList  list;

    @RequestMapping("/encuestas")
    public List<GlobalScores> list() {
        try {
            List<CeEncuestas> listaEncuestas = (List<CeEncuestas>) list.getAllCanalesDiario();
            

        }catch (Exception ex){
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return listaEncuestas;
    }

}
```

And my generic class with the entitymanager

```
package com.mytest.test.repository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Repository
@Transactional
public abstract class GenericEncuestasList<T> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager em;

    private Class<T> entityClass;
    

    public GenericEncuestasList(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public GenericEncuestasList() {
    }

    
    @Transactional
    public List<?> getAllCanalesDiario() {
        List<?> CeEncuestasList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
                
                TypedQuery<?> query = em.createQuery("Select c from CeEncuestas c", entityClass);
                CeEncuestasList = (List<T>) query.getResultList();
            }
            
        }catch (Exception ex){
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return CeEncuestasList;
    }

}
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
  <jta-data-source>java:/myDataDS</jta-data-source>
  <class>com.mytest.test.domain.CeEncuestas</class>
  
  <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

  <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>

  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And myapp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">
 
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mytest.test" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />



    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=""/>
    </bean>
    
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:/myDataDS" />

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="false" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    </bean>
    
    <!--<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
    </bean>-->

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="emf"/>

</beans>
```

Is there something I'm missing? I have to say, when I deploy the project with just Spring the app works fine, the thing is, I have to make my project a Spring Boot application in order to implement Keycloak in it.

Comment: Can you successfully built it without tests mvn package -DskipTests? Also Did you Changed @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnit") to @PersistenceContext(name = "persistenceUnit")

Comment: @Shay after I changed @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnit") to @PersistenceContext(name = "persistenceUnit") I got NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available; I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

You could try to override the #configure method in your Application class.
It seems like it is not picking up the configuration defined in your myapp-servlet.xml

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.mytest.test.repository")
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application){
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakSpringBootConfigResolver(){
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}
```

if that has no effect I think it still doesnt pickup the myapp-servlet.xml
Then you could try to annotate your Application class with

```java
@ImportResource("classpath:myapp-servlet.xml") // the xml file with the beans.
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {
...
```

assuming myapp-servlet.xml is in the src/main/resources folder.

see also:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-traditional-deployment
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-xml-beans